# How can I duplicate myself in a movie (using iMovie)?

Tags: imovie, macos

I would like to make a quite simple "special effect" in a short movie : showing "me" two times in the same room (for instance sitting at the same table and talking to each other).

Can I do this with iMovie and how ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are some good tutorials on this on Youtube [here](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=r2bLpFDK1wE&feature=fvwrel) and [here](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kXZY62MROAQ). The problem in both of these examples is the obvious lines where you can see the contrast and lightness changes.

However if you had either Adobe Premiere Elements or Adobe After effects this effect is a lot easier, and more professional [like this](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NYW2gr7mHhY&feature=fvst) you can find those tutorials [here (Premiere)](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xxX5eVFye4I&feature=related) and [here (After effects)](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=H9tIXeE8frU&feature=player_embedded)

Have a rummage around the [Creative Cow website](http://www.creativecow.net/) for good tutorials

Comment: "Clone yourself" : that was the right words to enter into google, not "duplicate". Thanks for your answer !

Comment: Actualy, Google isn't the best solution for tutorials, if you look at YouTube you will find one tutorial, and if thats not quite right, you can use the reccomendations on the right plane. If you are looking to learn I would go over to Creative Cow, its a great resource.

Answer (score 0):

For that you need to put the first video if yourself in one layer, and the other one on the layer on top of it, and crop the top one ([cropping tutorial](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=I-GTlp_1fps)). Crop it that the top one will who one of you, and the bottom the other one, when shooting the videos, just make sure that you always stay on one half of the frame (a DIFFERENT half every time).

Comment: In this tutorial, they explained how to crop a movie, but the screen ratio seems impossible to avoid. So it seems to be impossible to put 2 croped movies side by side, isn't it ?

Comment: motion 5 would work, or can't you crop the videos before-hand?